# Display image and resources problem

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I am using netbeans 6.9 with QT on ubuntu.
I want to display an image in my release build , but i got this error when compiling:

```
/usr/bin/rcc: File does not exist 'res.qrc'
```

This is my res.qrc file

```
    <RCC>
      <qresource prefix="image">
           <file>icon.gif</file>
      </qresource>
  </RCC>
```

In my qt-Release.pro i added:

```
RESOURCES   = res.qrc
```

My application runs but obviously my image won't be displayed.

res.qrc and the image is in my main project folder(where the source files are located).
Whats wrong? Am i missing anything? I studied the guide from 
[here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.0/resources.html)

Comment: shouldn't it be RESOURCES += res.qrc ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set `<qresource prefix="image">` but then note that

> the image is in my main project folder(where the source files are located)

That's one problem. It would need to be in the image folder.

Comment: Thanks :), creating the folder,relinking the gif image and it finally displays when i run my release build, but for strange reasons the compiler still complains the same error when i compile